# Basic Programming For Each Loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-interpolation

I have been breaking my head long enough to do this extremely simple thing but am unable to figure out how. I am trying to work this out in PowerShell.

```bsh
$IncidentID="INC0010164~INC0010165"
$arrIncidentID = $IncidentID -split '~'
$SysID = "d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d~7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec"
$arrSystemID = $SysID -split '~'

if ($arrIncidentID.Length -eq $arrSystemID.Length) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrIncidentID.length; $i++) {
        "The Incident ID is $arrIncidentID[$i] "
        "The URL is $arrSystemID[$i]"
    }
}
```

The result I get is

```
The Incident ID is INC0010164 INC0010165[0] 
The URL is d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d 7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec[0]
The Incident ID is INC0010164 INC0010165[1] 
The URL is d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d 7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec[1]
```

However, the format I am keen on is as below:

```
Incident ID 1: - INC0010164
SystemID 1: - d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d

Incident ID 2: - INC0010165 
SystemID 2: - 7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is intended to get your code functional and help you understand why it isn't working.

**Understanding the error**

Using a variable in a string and having it replace by its value is called string interpolation.  In PowerShell, interpolating variables themselves is easy.  You can also interpolate statements, but you need a little different syntax (which is `$()`).

```
$IncidentID="INC0010164~INC0010165"
$arrIncidentID = $IncidentID -split '~'
$SysID = "d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d~7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec"
$arrSystemID = $SysID -split '~'

if ($arrIncidentID.Length -eq $arrSystemID.Length) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrIncidentID.length; $i++) {
        "The Incident ID is $($arrIncidentID[$i]) "
        "The URL is $($arrSystemID[$i])"
    }
}
```

The new result is:

```
The Incident ID is INC0010164
The URL is d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d
The Incident ID is INC0010165
The URL is 7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec
```

**Better output**

So to get the final output you wanted, you could slightly adjust your code to:

```
$IncidentID="INC0010164~INC0010165"
$arrIncidentID = $IncidentID -split '~'
$SysID = "d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d~7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec"
$arrSystemID = $SysID -split '~'

if ($arrIncidentID.Length -eq $arrSystemID.Length) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrIncidentID.length; $i++) {
        "Incident ID $($i+1): - $($arrIncidentID[$i]) "
        "SystemID $($i+1): - $($arrSystemID[$i])"
    }
}
```

```
Incident ID 1: - INC0010164
SystemID 1: - d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d

Incident ID 2: - INC0010165 
SystemID 2: - 7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec
```

**The PowerShell Way**

You should consider doing this in a more PowerShell way to make it easier to reuse the output:

```
$IncidentID="INC0010164~INC0010165"
$arrIncidentID = $IncidentID -split '~'
$SysID = "d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d~7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec"
$arrSystemID = $SysID -split '~'

if ($arrIncidentID.Length -eq $arrSystemID.Length) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrIncidentID.length; $i++) {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            IncidentID = $arrIncidentID[$i]
            SystemID = $arrSystemID[$i]
        }
    }
}
```

```
IncidentID SystemID
---------- --------
INC0010164 d80fd7e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf96195d
INC0010165 7f0f97e2dbab4300479a7e7dbf9619ec
```

These are now objects that you can reference by property names.

Answer (score 0):

```
$IncidentID="INC0010164~INC0010165"
$arr = $IncidentID.Split("~")
foreach($val in $arr) {echo $val}
INC0010164
INC0010165
```

Works like a charme?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`-f`):

```bsh
for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrIncidentID.Length; $i++) {
    "Incident ID {0}: - {1}`nSystemID {0}: - {2}" -f ($i+1), $arrIncidentID[$i], $arrSystemID[$i]
}
```